# How to use the generated 3D point cloud in RGBDSLAM package for localization?

Tags: ros, rgbdslamv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have generated RGBD map using " RGBDSLAMv2" package and wanted to perform localization in 3D environment.How can this be achieved? has anyone done it?. Can i use the package "humanoid_ navigation" package with " RGBDSLAMv2" package to achieve the same?Please guide me i am novice in this.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224673/how-to-use-the-generated-3d-point-cloud-in-rgbdslam-package-for-localization?/) by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2016-01-22**:
So is there any other way you know?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-02-09**:
No, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For rgbdslam_v2 localization with an existing map is not possible. I do not know whether the humanoid navigation package can do this.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0